# Certain content type not showing during search in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have 2 content types named `pages` and `article`.When I use `drupal search` i get results for which `content-type` is `page`,but i can't get the results that I have with `content-type` is `article`.Is their any `setting` to filter my result or could i do it programatically.?Could someone help me to help me filter my search results.

Comment: try to run cron,re-index site

Comment: tanx @vimal.tat did the trick... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run `cron`,`re-index` the website.This would reindex the site and enables search on newly created indexes.